# Is it possible (in PHP) to create an IF statement that checks to see if many variables (ie. $var1, $var2, etc) have a value?

Tags: php, if-statement

Is it possible (in PHP) to create an IF statement that checks to see if many variables (ie. $var1, $var2, etc.) have a value, such as "Heavy" and if one of those variables do, then do xyz...

For example, can I write:

```
 if ($row["wp1"] || $row["wp2"] || $row["wp2"] == "Heavy")
 { 
     echo "do this";
 }
```

I tried the above and it's not working. The script runs but the IF part doesn't actually work.

Comment: `if(in_array("Heavy", [$row['wp1'], $row['wp2'], $row['wp3']]))`

Comment: This is the same problem as the duplicate, but instead of looking for a variable in an array of constants, you're looking for a constant in an array of variables.

Comment: @nice_dev shows how to do it in their comment.